# Pass Cmdlet as parameter to Function

Tags: powershell

There are a couple good answers about passing functions

```
function pass_function([scriptblock] $func, [int] $a){
  func.invoke($a)
}
```

How would you pass Cmdlets that accept piped input? I have a poor solution

```
function pass_through([scriptblock]$command){
  $command.invoke()
}

1,2,3,4 | pass_through { $input | Where { $_ -gt 1} }
```

outputs 2, 3, 4.

Technically there are enough tools there, but they require implementation fiddling. I would prefer to pass Where and {$_ -gt 1} as separate parameters.

If there isn't good support for this, what is this language's style for solving similar problems?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are doing it this way? Meta programming is fun and all but I am curious. Why can you not make a dedicated function that accepts that parameters you want... process and continue with the pipeline.

Comment: The example was chosen for simplicity. But suppose I have a "logging" tool that tests the effect of a CmdLet on piped input. So we might have 
"input | remember | chosenCmdLet | difference"
Where "remember" might tag the values in some way, and "difference" signaled when an element in the stream was removed or changed. It would be nice if I could just call Test chosenCmdLet instead of calling it between these two Cmdlets.

Comment: @Polymer `function Test{param([ScriptBlock]$Command)input|remember|Invoke-Command $Command|difference}` `Test {Where { $_ -gt 1}}`

Comment: Invoke-Command correctly pipes objects into and out of the script block? If true that's really cool, is there a nice article that talks a little bit about this? Most stuff I see about Invoke-Command discusses its use over networks.

Comment: @Polymer If script block can be converted to `SteppablePipeline` and does not contain direct reference to `$input`, then `Invoke-Command` invoke it as `SteppablePipeline`. I actually find this out by digging in with ILSpy. Sorry, by I can not point you to any article about that.

Comment: That's fine, if you post your comments as an answer I'll mark it as correct. It seems to solve the general problem, and it's very straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a way to change command in the middle of pipeline without writing another copy of pipeline. You can achieve that by invoking `ScriptBlock` as `SteppablePipeline`. Nice thing is that `Invoke-Command` cmdlet can do that for you, if all following conditions are meet:

- `Invoke-Command` expect pipeline input.
- `ScriptBlock` does not have direct reference to `$input`.
- `ScriptBlock` convertible to `SteppablePipeline`.

Here is `Pass_Through` function:

```
function Pass_Through {
    param(
        [ScriptBlock]$MiddleCommand
    )
    $input|
    Pre-Command|
    Invoke-Command $MiddleCommand|
    Post-Command
}
```

And you can invoke it like this:

```
1..10|Pass_Through {Where { $_ -gt 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that different cmdlets are going to have different ways to invoke them. Such as, passing 1,2,3,4 to a `Where` clause is fine, it likes arrays of just about anything, but you can't pass that to `Format-Table` because it simply doesn't take an array of strings, it needs an array of objects.

For your `Where` purpose you could do something like:

```
Function Pass_Through {
Param(
    [string]$Cmd,
    [string]$Arguments
)
Process{[scriptblock]::Create("`$input|$cmd $arguments").Invoke()}
}
```

Then when we do:

```
1,2,3,4 | pass_through 'Where' '{ $_ -gt 1}'
```

It responds with 2, 3, 4 as expected.
But what happens when you want to pass an object and not a string?

```
Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME | Pass_Through 'Format-Table' 'Name,DistinguishedName'
```

Not going to happen, because it tries to extrapolate each property and pass each string to the `Format-Table` cmdlet, and that just doesn't work.

Comment: I voted this as correct, since it solves the general problem exactly. Though, because I'm new to this, I'm not sure how I would specify a CmdLet from a weird namespace.

Wouldn't you want Process to be End instead?

And, how would you personally solve these sorts of problems? Because this feels a little forced.

Comment: You should escape `$input` in you script block: ``"`$input|$cmd $arguments"``. Try this: `'dir'|Pass_Through foreach '{$_}'`. It does not print `dir`, but result of `dir` command.

Comment: @PetSerAl Excellent suggestion! I have made the change in my answer.

Comment: @Polymer I considered doing `End{}` but then you have to use a `ForEach` loop to account for arrays being passed to the function. I'm not sure, but maybe a `Filter` would be better suited for this kind of thing. I have a hard time knowing when to use a filter instead of a function.